# How can I list all objects associated to a particular object via foreign key in Django?

Tags: django, listview, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

I have a ListView that lists all Vehicle objects. How can I make another view, that would show a list of all Job objects associated with that vehicle when I click on the link marked ### next to that vehicle?

**models.py**

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehicle_reg = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=7)
    vehicle_make = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    vehicle_model = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Job(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**html**

```
 <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="table-light">
          <th scope="col">Registration</th>
          <th scope="col">Make</th>
          <th scope="col">Model</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for vehicle in vehicleList %}
      <tr class="table-light">
        <td class="lead">
          <a href="{% url '###' pk=vehicle.pk %}">{{vehicle.vehicle_reg}}</a></td>
        <td class="lead">{{vehicle.vehicle_make}}</td>
        <td class="lead">{{vehicle.vehicle_model}}</td>
      </tr>
```

**views.py**

```
class VehicleListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'vehicleList'
    model = Vehicle
    template_name = 'vehicles/vehicle_list.html'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
# detail view for vehicle 
class VehicleDetailView(DetailView):
     model = Vehicle 
     template_name = 'your_template'
     context_object_name = 'vehicle'

# urls.py
   path('vehicle/<int:pk>/detail/', VehicleDetailView.as_view(), name='vehicle_detail')

# your_list_template      
 {% for vehicle in vehicleList %}
    ......
     <a href="{% url 'vehicle_detail' vehicle.pk %}">{{vehicle}}</a>
 {% endfor %}

 # vehicle detail template
  {% for job in vehicle.job_set.all %}
      ...
   {{job}}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a separate view and parse the foreign key ID into that view (through urls). Then in that view, since you are using class based views, overwrite `get_queryset` with Job.objects.filter(car_id=kwargs.get('vehicle_id'))

```
class JobListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'jobList'
    model = Job
    template_name = 'vehicles/job_list.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Job.objects.filter(vehicle_id=self.kwargs.get('vehicle_id'))
        return qs
```